# Using (static)HTML Controls in Code-Behind, Coding with C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am working in VS10 using C# in ASP.NET. In my design form, I have a textArea(standard HTML control).

```
 <textarea id="Text1"  rows = "8"; cols="30" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)"   name="S1"> </textarea>
```

Now in my code-behind page, I am using C# to code the controls. I have given the textArea an auto-expand functionality which I require thru out my project. I need this TextArea as a server control, like when we put a textBox in the design page, we can use it in the code-behind page to code, since it is a server control. However, textArea isn't a server control.
I have gone thru the previous posts on the site but i did not get anything enough useful.
I have even tried using [<% %>] system, and [runat="server"] but it did not help.
What i wanna do is to use the textArea in the Code-behind page, i.e. call it in the coding space, just like we can call the TextBox control objects.
So, can anyone please help me with this,,,
Regards..
javascript for autogrowing text box is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

function AutoGrowTextArea(textField)
```

{

```
if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight) 

{

 textField.style.height = textField.scrollHeight + "px";

 if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight)

{

textField.style.height = (textField.scrollHeight * 2 - textField.clientHeight) + "px";

} 

}

} 

</script>
```

Comment: remove the `;` after `row="8"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

add `runat="server"` to the tag

```
<textarea id="Text1" runat="server"  rows = "8" cols="30" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" name="S1"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate raw html controls setting the **runat="server"** propery of the control.

```
 <textarea id="Text1" runat="server"  rows = "8"; cols="30" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)"   name="S1"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox id="thisIsMyTextBox" runat="server" multiline="true" width="200px" onkeyup="AutoGrowTextArea(this)" height="80px" style="resize:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can play with the width/height as you wish !

> function AutoGrowTextArea(textField)
>
> {
>
> ```
>    if(textField.Lenght()%50==0)//50 is the number of character in your textbox
>
>    {
>
>             if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight) 
>
>             {
>
>                     textField.style.height = textField.scrollHeight + "px";
>
>                     if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight)
>
>                     {
>
>                              textField.style.height = (textField.scrollHeight * 2 - textField.clientHeight) + "px";
>
>                     } 
>
>      }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Well, i tried that. I have the javascript:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function AutoGrowTextArea(textField) {
            if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight) {
                textField.style.height = textField.scrollHeight + "px";
                if (textField.clientHeight < textField.scrollHeight) {
                    textField.style.height =
        (textField.scrollHeight * 2 - textField.clientHeight) + "px";
                }
            }
        }
</script>

Comment: doing what you said just increase the height of the text area on each key press, i just want to increase the height, at the end of line[facebook comment system]

Comment: The line I wrote should work okay, I think it's your javascript that isn't working properly, may be add that bit of code to your main post so I can study it indented please ?

Comment: The JavaScript has been written :)

Comment: I would use modulo for this, if textbox%30==0 (execute rest of the javascript code). I'm editing my post right now

Answer (score 0):

You can add runat="server" in your markup and it will be a server control.

You can also create server controls in your code behind. Declaration (In Visual Basic):

```
Protected WithEvents foo As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("textarea")
```

If you want to use something in all your project, you can declare a class inherited from Control or HtmlGenericControl and you can implement whatever you need to implement everywhere where you your new control.